# I'm Having trouble with Javascript. It says that "TypeError: document.forms.inputs is undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm struggling for this work, and I couldn't get help from any other valuable resources. I guess the main problem is the referencing of the variables in the DOM format.
I have the code right here(I'm not sharing the CSS as it may not be important in this error)

`

```
<script>
var a, b, c;
a = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_2"].value;
b = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_1"].value;
c = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_0"].value;
  var D = b^2 - 4*a*c;

  var ans1 = (-b + sqrt(D)/2*a);
  var ans2 = (-b - sqrt(D)/2*a);


function result(){

    document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = ans1;
    document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = ans2;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "head">
<h1 class = "head">  Quad Root Finder </h1>
  </div>
  <div class = "message">
<h3 class = "message">  Hello user, I am making this Quad Root Finder as one of my starting project. </h3>
  </div>
<div class = "derivative">
<form name = "inputs">
    <input type="text" name = "deg_2" ></input><lable for = "x^2"> x^2 +  </lable>
    <input type = "text" name = "deg_1"></input><lable for = "x"> x +  </lable>
    <input type = "text" name = "deg_0"></input><lable for = "constant"> </lable><br><br>
    <button onclick="result()"> Find Roots </button>
</form>
</div>
<p class = "answer_title">
Answer:
</p>
<div class = "answer">
    <h3 id = "answer1"> </h3>
    <h3 id = "answer2"> </h3>
</div>
</body>
```

`

Comment: You must put all that code inside the `result()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting your error is because your JavaScript code is at the top of your HTML page. This means it gets executed before your HTML gets parsed. Therefore, when your code gets run, the elements don't exist as far as the browser's DOM is concerned.

As is pointed out in the comments of the question, you should move all of that logic within your `result` function otherwise `ans1` and `ans2` will only ever have the original value when the page loads.

As good practice, you should also move your JavaScript to the bottom of your HTML in order to allow the DOM to be loaded before it executes.

```
<body>
    // All your other HTML
    <script>
        function result(){
            var a, b, c;
            a = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_2"].value;
            b = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_1"].value;
            c = document.forms["inputs"]["deg_0"].value;
            var D = b^2 - 4*a*c;

            var ans1 = (-b + sqrt(D)/2*a);
            var ans2 = (-b - sqrt(D)/2*a);
            document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = ans1;
            document.getElementById('answer2').innerHTML = ans2;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```